# Mongoose update embedded document does not work

Tags: node.js, mongoose

Greeting all,

I defined a deeply embedded mongoose model "Person", which contains a field "Contact", and "Contact" has an array of "Address" for this person's work, home, delivery etc addresses.

When I wanted to update an address, and use the model's "save" function, the change wasn't reflected in the database.

```
            console.log(person.Contact.Address[i].City = 'Chicago');
            person.save(function (err) {
                if (!err) {
                   console.log(person.Contact.Address[i].City);
```

The console.log indicates that the field City has been updated to new value, but the mongodb's value stays the same.

Could you please help me with this issue?

Thanks!
Gary

Answer (score 5):

The issue was resolved by using [`markModified`](http://mongoosejs.com/docs/api.html#document_Document-markModified):

```
person.markModified('Contact.Address');
person.save()
```

Still not sure when I need to use  `markModified`, because in most other cases the change was reflected in mongodb without using it.

Comment: I think this has something to do with mixed data types

Comment: Any field in your schema with a `type` of either: `Mixed, {}, Array, []` require the use of `markModified` when its contents are changed.  You shouldn't need it otherwise.

Comment: Just for info., `markModified` would work just once per same request. If you try to re-use it for same request, it can throw duplicate entry error.