# Update subarray of strings

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I'm trying to update item in subarray of document. Type of subarray is array of strings:

```
Dictionary.findOne({ name: req.query.name }, function(err1, data){
        if(err1){
            logger.error(err1);
            res.send({ err: 'Db error' });
        } else {
            var index = data.values.indexOf(req.query.value);
            if(index == -1)
                res.send({ err: 'Value not found' });
            else {
                data.values[index] = req.query.newValue;
                data.save(function(err2){
                    if(err2){
                        logger.error(err);
                        res.send({ err: 'Db error' });
                    } else
                        res.send({ data: data, info: 'Dictionary updated successfully' });
                });
            }
        }
    });
```

returned `data` is updated correctly, but record is not updated in database. Help please

Comment: Possible duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14922311/mongoose-update-embedded-document-does-not-work

Answer (score 1, accepted):

from mongodb shell you can write

```
db.test.update({values:"English"},{$set:{'values.1':"updated value"}})
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to mark the change before saving it

```
data.markModified 'values'
data.save (...)
```

http://mongoosejs.com/docs/api.html#types_embedded_EmbeddedDocument-markModified

Comment: Thanks so much, it helped. One more question- is it right to do so?